# I want to create a search box for JSON data using JavaScript and get a popup if content exists or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, wordpress

I have this code to search through my JSON data, but I
want when I search, I get a popup saying if it exists or not in my JSON file. How can I fix it?

I basically need an HTML search box to search through corresponding JSON data and return the result in a popup:

[image]

```js
var data = [
   {
      "id":198,
      "name":"Aaron Garo",
   },
   {
      "id":345,
      "name":"Michael Stines",
   },
   {
      "id":545,
      "name":"Ully Heiz",
   },
   {
      "id":678,
      "name":"Asgaf Torino",
   }
]

output = "";
$.each(data, function(key, val){
    output += "<div class='values'>";
      output += '<h5 class="value-id">' + val.id + '</h5>';
      output += '<p class="value-name">' + val.name + '</p>'
  output += "</div>";
});

$('#content').html(output);

/* SEEKER FUNCTION */
 if (!RegExp.escape) {
   RegExp.escape = function (s) {
     return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
   };
 }

jQuery(function(){
  var $rows = $('.values');
  $('#seeker').keyup(function () {
    var regex =  new RegExp(RegExp.escape($.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')), 'i')
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
      var text = $(this).children(".value-name").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return regex.test(text)
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.values{
  background: #FFFFAA;
}

.search-bar{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="seeker">
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan want When I search, I get a popup saying if it exists or not in my json file .

Comment: The search does not handle numbers right now. You only want a popup when people type a number?

Answer (score 0):

You may mean like this:

```js
var data = [{ "id":198, "name":"Aaron Garo" },{ "id":345, "name":"Michael Stines" },{ "id":545, "name":"Ully Heiz" },{ "id":678, "name":"Asgaf Torino"}];


$('#content').html(data.map(({id,name}) => `<div class='values'><h5 class="value-id">${id}</h5><p class="value-name">${name}</p></div>`));

/* SEEKER FUNCTION */
 if (!RegExp.escape) RegExp.escape = s => s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");

$(function(){
  var $rows = $('.values');
  $('#seeker').keyup(function () {
    var regex =  new RegExp(RegExp.escape($.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')), 'i')
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
      var text = $(this).children(".value-name").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return regex.test(text)
    }).show();
    const count = $(":visible",$rows).length;
    $("#res").text(count/2 +" found").toggle(count > 0)
  });
});
```

```css
.values{
  background: #FFFFAA;
}

.search-bar{
  width: 100%;
}
#res { display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="seeker"> <span id="res"></span>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Just popup when click search saying if content exists or not exists Like when i create Aaron Garo and then click search  show popup this name existe or This Name not existes

Comment: Please make some kind of drawing. I do not understand

Comment: I added a picture thank you

Answer (score 0):

Precisely what you need

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 198,
    "name": "Aaron Garo",
  },
  {
    "id": 345,
    "name": "Michael Stines",
  },
  {
    "id": 545,
    "name": "Ully Heiz",
  },
  {
    "id": 678,
    "name": "Asgaf Torino",
  }
]

output = "";
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  output += `<option value="Name : ${val.name} ; ID : ${val.id}" />`
});

$('#names').html(output);

$('#mybtn').click(() => {
  var name = document.getElementById("seeker").value.split(": ")[1].split(" ;")[0];
  if (data.find(o => o.name == name)) {
    alert("value does exist");
  } else {
    alert("value does not exist");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="seeker" list="names">
  <datalist id="names">
  </datalist>
  <button id="mybtn" role="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi I Have edited the snippet please check wether thats what you want. if yes please accept my answer